# Why is my program got into an infinite loop?

Tags: c, string, while-loop, scanf, infinite-loop

I want to scan a line until newline is pressed. I'm aware of `gets()` function, but I wanted to learn it with `scanf()`. The problem is, that my program falls into an infinite loop, where it scans the input from user and then infinitely prints it out, where it should print once after each scan. Can anybody explain why is it behaving like this?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char str[100];
    while(str[0]!='\0')
    {
        scanf("%[^\n]",str);
        printf("%s\n",str);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you test `str[0]` for the first time, it is uninitialised. `scanf` returns a value; use it.

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]",str);` 1st time remain newline. 2nd time and after that, It is rejected. Also `str[0]!='\0'` at first time, Using uninitialize variable.

Comment: "I'm aware of gets() function" - but are you aware that it is obsolete and should not be used?

Comment: Last I checked, `scanf` didn't accept regexes. Which is what it looks like you're doing.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe It's not a regex. It's a format specifier that says to not read the the character after the ^. See https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf

Comment: Ah. I've never seen that before. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insist on using scanf, then change format specifier:

```
" %[^\n]"
```

The space in front will skip any previous "dangling" \n

Also you should initialize the str array before checking the contents of it, better yet use a `do-while-loop` instead .

Something like this should work

```
char str[100] = {0};
do
{
    scanf(" %[^\n]",str);
    printf("%s\n",str);
}
while(str[0]!='q');
```

Personally I prefer to use `fgets(...)` in combination with `sscanf(...)`
Also it is good practice to check the return value of scanf, there is a return value for a purpose.

added another while condition, loops until "q" or "quit"

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that the space in the format specifier will eat up the left over \n.

Comment: `while(str[0]!='\0');` Meaningless.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY so true /facepalm

Answer (score 1):

Since `%[^\n]` does not accept newline, input is not accepted in the second loop.

Probably, this will do what you want.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char str[100];

    while(1== scanf("%99[^\n]%*c",str)){//%*c consumes newline. Also In case of only newline terminates the loop
        printf("%s\n",str);
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice. I didn't know you could specify %*c. Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

BLUEPIXY is absolutely correct. The first return from `scanf()` is leaving the `\n` in the input buffer. Subsequent `scanf()` calls will return right away without reading any characters from `stdin` because `scanf()` stops reading on a `\n`. So a loop ensues. One way to avoid the loop is to read the `\n` from the input after the call to `scanf()` as shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[100] = {0};

    do
    {
        scanf("%[^\n]",str);
        getchar();
        printf("%s\n",str);
    }while( str[0] != '\0' );
}
```

You seem to be under some false beliefs regarding how input works. So I'm going to explain below.

You don't need to do this in a loop because `scanf()` doesn't read and return one character at a time when you specify a string format. The input is `buffered` by the terminal. When you ask `scanf()` to return a string, the terminal will only send the input string to `scanf()` when it a `newline` is received. When that happens `scanf()` returns the string without the `newline`.

You'll need to do extra work to turn off terminal line buffering. The below example code shows how to turn off terminal I/O buffering.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>

int main()
{
    struct termios old_tio, new_tio;
    unsigned char c;

    /* get the terminal settings for stdin */
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO,&old_tio);

    /* we want to keep the old setting to restore them a the end */
    new_tio=old_tio;

    /* disable canonical mode (buffered i/o) and local echo */
    new_tio.c_lflag &=(~ICANON & ~ECHO);

    /* set the new settings immediately */
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO,TCSANOW,&new_tio);

    do {
         c=getchar();
         printf("%c ",(char)c);
    } while(c!='q');

    /* restore the former settings */
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO,TCSANOW,&old_tio);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the downvote. I realize my initial answer didn't actually answer the question. I believe my answer is now valid.